# lifting performance of query

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, subquery, query-optimization

I'm building a forum app in which users can post messages. These messages can be seen by others.

Table structure (simplified):

```
// table: users
user_id | username | gender
---------------------------
1       | john     | m
2       | jane     | f
...

// table: posts
post_id | user_id | title
-------------------------
1       | 1       | Hello
...

// table: views
view_id | post_id | user_id | timestamp
---------------------------------------
1       | 1       | 2       | 2020-01-01 12:00:00
...
```

Now I want to create a query to return some statistics about this post. I want to get the unique views (every time a user views a post, this is logged, but I only want to count all users once) and I want to get the ratio male/female.

```
SELECT
    title,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM views WHERE post_id = 1) AS unique_views,
    (SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM users WHERE gender = 'm' AND user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM views WHERE post_id = 1) AS male_views,
    (SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM users WHERE gender = 'f' AND user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM views WHERE post_id = 1) AS female_views
FROM
    posts
WHERE
    post_id = 1
```

The query works, but it's a query with 5 subqueries. I don't have a lot of data to test on yet, but I'm afraid performance will drop when I have let's say +1m users, +1m posts and +10m views.

A different approach would be to completely split the query into multiple queries: one for the total unique views, on for the gender views (with a distinct), but then it would still be 6 queries in total.

I'm using postgresql and I have an index on `users.user_id`, `users.gender`, `posts.post_id`, `views.view_id`, `views.post_id`.

**Question:** is there another way (for example with JOINs) to execute this query, and would have better performance when the volume of the database increases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join and do conditional aggregation instead of nesting subqueries:

```
select 
    p.title,
    count(distinct u.user_id) unique_views,
    count(u.user_id) filter(where u.gender = 'm') male_views,
    count(u.user_id) filter(where u.gender = 'f') female_views
from views v
inner join users u on u.user_id = v.user_id
inner join posts p on p.post_id = v.post_id
where p.post_id = 1
group by p.post_id, p.title
```